# Parse JSON find value and append random number?

Tags: python, json, input

I have a JSON file with login and integer valuer (some result), like this:

```
[
        {
           "name":"Tamara",
           "results":"434.545.234.664"
        },
        {
           "name":"Ted",
           "results":"434.545.234.664"
        }
]
```

I need to receive user login (name), find inserted name in JSON. If it already exists, add some number to the "results".

For example: If I input "Ted", some number will be appended to Ted's results like this: `"results":"434.545.234.664+4343}"`

If name doesn't exist, add new record with:

```
{
    "name":"new_name",
    "results":"some_number"
}
```

in it.

My code, which didn't work:

```
with open('/Users/users_db.json') as jsonfile:
    user_name = ''
    while user_name == '':
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
        user_name = input('Your name: ')
        for user in data:
            if user_name in user['name']:
                print('Old user')
                break
            else:
                print('New user')
```

Comment: Are all names unique? Also what is `some_number`?

Comment: So what's your question? You know what you want, now it's time to start hacking some code ;)
Using the `json` library in python, this certainly possible and actually quite trivial.

Comment: have you tried to do this yourself? show us your code

Comment: "434.545.234.664" is really not an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the zillion possible ways to code your problem:

```
import json
import random
import names

random.seed(1)

data = [
    {
        "name": "Tamara",
        "results": "434.545.234.664"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ted",
        "results": "434.545.234.664"
    }
]


def foo(lst, name):
    some_number = random.randint(0, 4343)
    values = filter(lambda d: d["name"] == name, lst)

    if values:
        for v in values:
            v["results"] += "+{0}".format(some_number)
    else:
        lst.append({
            "name": name,
            "results": some_number
        })

for name in ["Tamara", "Ted"] + [names.get_first_name() for i in range(8)]:
    foo(data, name)

print(data)
```

This one will use [names](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/names/) module to generate random test names.

One advice though, take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can [parse your json](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) like this

```
import json

with open('yourJsonFile.json') as example_data:
    data = json.load(example_data)
```

And now it's a matter of working with `data` to find whatever you need. For example, to access the first name you could do

```
data[0]['name']
```

The rest depends on where/how you store the names and check if they already exist.

Finally, to add a new value you can use `append`